# Alternative for "listen to" when referring to a video game soundtrack

Tags: synonyms

I am writing a list of bullets to describe my video game, and I am stuck on the one about the soundtrack.

Here's what I am doing:

- Play a cast of...
- Save up coins to...
- Explore a world of...
- Unlock and master the...

What verb can I use for the soundtrack?

There is **listen to**, but that sounds kinda lame. **Tune in** doesn't work either, because it makes me think of a radio station.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about *Immerse yourself in...* ?

[Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/immerse) has:

> To engage wholly or deeply; absorb.